# Configure Laravel on a subdomain with Nginx on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: laravel, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My Laravel application runs locally and remotely on the main domain (https://www.example.com and https://example.com), but my staging environment doesn't work. The main page works, but other routes don't (I get a 504).

The nginx.conf I use is the following:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    gzip_static on;
    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = 'http'){
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}
```

How do I add https://staging.example.com to this configuration?

Comment: How did you setup the nginx, using `.ebextentions`? Also do you use EB platform based on Amazon Linux 1 or 2?

Comment: @Marcin Yes, .ebextensions. Linux 2.

Comment: Hi. The staging environment is a separate EB environment? Is it single-instance or load-balanced environment?

Comment: Load balanced and a second EB environment (cloned from production).

Comment: If its load balanced environment, redirections from http to https should be done on your ALB. the SSL cert should be deployed on the ALB. And the domain `staging.example.com` is set using Route53? I'm not sure why are you redirecting http to https using nginx if you use load-balanced environment?

Comment: Try this?
`location / {`
        `root   /var/www/html/staging.example.com/public;`
        `index index.php index.html index.htm;`
        `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;`
    `}`
Sorry for bad formatting. :/

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Amazon Linux 2 (AL2), this could explain why your nginx config file is not used.

Specifically, on AL2 platforms, nginx config files [should be set](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html) in `.platform/nginx/conf.d/`, not in `.ebextensions`. The nginx were setup using `.ebextentions` in AL1, but not in AL2.

Thus, you could try creating file `.platform/nginx/conf.d/myconf.conf` with the content:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    gzip_static on;
    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = 'http'){
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}
```

Please note, I can't verify whether the nginx config file is correct. It's just based on your question. It could also have mistakes.

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed I have that file in both locations. Also under .platform/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/laravel.conf.

Comment: @Sherlock So probably there's something wrong with the configuration itself. Can you ssh into the EB instance and manually apply it, restart nginx and check if it works as expected?

Comment: done but it still doesn't work. I don't think the config itself is wrong; this is the file that works on https://example.com and https://www.example.com. I just think it's lacking subdomain support, but I know know how I should fix that.

Comment: @Sherlock Ok. Hopefully it will work out. Please, let me know how it will go. By the way, the nginx file in `.ebextentions` is redundant. On AL2, `.platform` should be used for nginx.